# （UITableView上に）ポップアップを表示したい！

Tags: swift, xcode

`TableViewController` に　`PopupViewController` のポップアップを表示したいのですがうまく行かないです。　何故なのでしょうか。どうしたら良いですか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
** この右側のポップアップを表示したい**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↓↓こうなります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**TableViewのクラス**

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var array : Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! costomViewCell

        cell.skillName.text = "〇〇〇〇〇〇\(array[indexPath.row])"
        cell.goalCountLabel.text = "20 : 00"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }


    let popupViewController = PopupViewController()
    @IBAction func addSkillButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        view.addSubview(popupViewController.view)
    }


    @IBAction func secret(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }


}
```

**Popupクラス**

```swift
import UIKit

class PopupViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newSkillView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newSkillLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var newSkillText: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(
            red: 150/255,
            green: 150/255,
            blue: 150/255,
            alpha: 0.6
        )
     // newSkillView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0 この処理を行うとThread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value というエラーが出る。。。何故？？？

    }

    @IBAction func newSkillButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func tapGestureRecogButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**こうなります** の画像を見ると、table viewの部分がグレーになっていますよね? これは`PopupViewController`が **表示はされているけど、中身がない** 状態になっているからです。

この事象でいちばんの元凶はこの行です。

```
    let popupViewController = PopupViewController()
```

view controllerの引数なしのイニシャライザを呼んでいますが、これではiOSは、storyboardの中身を読みに行ってくれません。

従って、

- IBOutletは接続してくれない

  `newSkillView`はnilのままなんで、実行時にUnexpectedly found nilになる
- IBActionは接続してくれない
- そもそもstoryboardエディタ上で作成したデザインは一切反映してくれない

  `UIView`も`UILabel`も`UITextField`も、一切画面に現れないことになります。

---

今回の事象の直接の原因にはなっていませんが、あなたのコードにはもう一つ致命的にまずい点があります。

```
        view.addSubview(popupViewController.view)
```

view controllerの`view`だけを別のview controllerの支配下にある`view`に`addSubview(_:)`で追加しています。

iOSでは、

- 全ての`UIView`は一つのview controllerの支配下にある
- `UIViewController`用のメソッドには「現在表示を担当している」か「現在アクティブなview controllerチェーンの一部である」かで無いと動かないものがある

と言うことで、現在のあなたのコードでは`PopupViewController`は表示されています(先ほど書いたように中身は無いですが)が、今後`PopupViewController`にいろんなコードを足していって、上記のようなチェックに引っかかるメソッドを使うと、実行時エラーになってしまいます。

---

と言うわけで、iOSで「ポップアップを表示」する場合、一般的(storyboardを使う場合)には、

- 普通に表示されるポップアップをstoryboardでデザインする

  背景色の一部はポップアップっぽく半透明にしますが、これはstoryboard上で設定できます
- storyboard上でポップアップのView Controller属性 **Presentation** を **Over Current Context** にしてやる

  [image: Over Current Context]
- 必ずstoryboardが使われるようにインスタンス化する
- 後は普通に`present`などで表示してやる

と言う手順になります。

コードの方の修正は、例えばこんな感じです。

**TableViewのクラス**

```
    //インスタンスプロパティとしての`popupViewController`は不要
    @IBAction func addSkillButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //元(`TableViewController`)と同じstoryboardは`self.storyboard`で取得できる
        let storyboard = self.storyboard!
        //storyboardからインスタンス化すると、iOSがいろいろと面倒を見てくれる
        let popupViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController

        //普通のview controllerとして、presentで表示する
        self.present(popupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

セグエを使ってもstoryboardは読み込まれるんですが、説明が書きにくいので今回は`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`を使っています。(storyboard上でポップアップの **Storyboard ID** をコードに合わせて`PopupViewController`にしてやる必要があります。)

**Popupクラス**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //...
        //Storyboardを通じてインスタンス化するとIBOutletを接続してくれるので実行時エラーにならない
        newSkillView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0

    }

    //...

    @IBAction func tapGestureRecogButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //普通のview controllerとして、presentで表示するので、dismissで元に戻れる
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

---

と、ここまででポップアップ表示はできるはずなんですが、ポップアップでOKを押すとtable viewの方に結果が反映されないといけませんよね。[以前の別質問に対する回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55758/13972)の応用(と言うよりコアな部分は殆どそのまんま)なんで、説明軽めにコードだけ示しておきます。

**Popupクラス**
デリゲート用のプロトコル、デリゲートプロパティ、デリゲートの呼び出しを追加。

```
//delegate用のプロトコルを宣言する
protocol PopupViewControllerDelegate: class {
    //`label`は、今は`Int`にしておく
    func popupViewController(_ popupVC: PopupViewController, didEnterLabel label: Int)
}
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {
    //`delegate`変数をweakで宣言する
    weak var delegate: PopupViewControllerDelegate?

    //...

    @IBAction func newSkillButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //`label`は、今は`Int`にしてある
        let label = Int(newSkillText.text ?? "") ?? 0
        //その`label`の値を使ってdelegateメソッドを呼び出す
        delegate?.popupViewController(self, didEnterLabel: label)
    }

    //...
}
```

**TableViewのクラス**
`PopupViewController`のデリゲートは自分であることを宣言してやる

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //...

    //↓`###`のある行を追加
    //インスタンスプロパティとしての`popupViewController`は不要
    @IBAction func addSkillButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //元(`TableViewController`)と同じstoryboardは`self.storyboard`で取得できる
        let storyboard = self.storyboard!
        //storyboardからインスタンス化すると、iOSがいろいろと面倒を見てくれる
        let popupViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
        popupViewController.delegate = self //### `PopupViewController`のdelegateは自分(`self`)が引き受ける
        //普通のview controllerとして、presentで表示する
        self.present(popupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //...
}

//`PopupViewControllerDelegate`としてのお仕事を定義する
extension TableViewController: PopupViewControllerDelegate {

    func popupViewController(_ popupVC: PopupViewController, didEnterLabel label: Int) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: array.count, section: 0)
        array.append(label)
        //↑↓辻褄を合わせる
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        popupVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: すいませんありがとうございます。自作のポップアップを一度やめてデフォルトのポップアップにtextFeldをつけたものを採用したのですが、今から自作のポップアップに変更したいと思います。話は逸れてしまいますが、私はOOPer様がおりませんだらとうの昔に挫折していました。しかし、こうしてOOPer様のお力添えでappが着々と完成に向かうことができ深謝致しております。　ですが私は他力の度が過ぎている様に思われます。そこでどうすれば自力で問題を解決できるかを問題解決における具体的な解決手順などを教えていただきたく思います。どうかよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: @ahoahomarumaru さん、コメントありがとうございます。デフォルトのポップアップと言うのがどれのことかはわからないのですが、(練習は別にして)実際に採用するのはご自身が望む機能を十分に実現できるんなら、「Q&Aサイトで回答もらったから」なんて気を使う必要はないと思いますよ。「具体的な解決手順」と言うのは問題ごとに変わってくるので、コメント欄に一言でまとめるのは難しいですが、「できるだけ原典に近い情報をあたる」なんてことは遠回りに見えてもやっておいた方が良いでしょう。例えば今回なら[AppleのView Controllerに関する記事](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)とか。日本語版はどっかいっちゃったし、Appleのドキュメント構成はお世辞にもわかりやすいとは言えないんですが、時々ざっくりとでも記事を眺めておく(理解しようなんて思わなくて良い)と「ios ポップアップ」なんて検索結果から、どれが使えるか使うべきか、判断しやすくなると思います。

Comment: また、連日質問を書かれていると「他力の度が過ぎている」と感じられると言うのは理解できなくはないですが、果たして本当にそうでしょうか? 今のように連日アプリを発展させて新しい機能を実現しようとしているのであれば、新しい疑問が出てくるのは、ある意味当然ではないでしょうか? 『過去のQ&Aの内容が理解できていれば、こんな質問は出ないでしょ』なんて質問を連発するのは困りものですが、新しい事柄に直面した時にわからないことがあるのはむしろ当然です。プログラミングの学習で「遠回り」はあっても、「近道」はありません。先に書いたようなことを意識していれば、段々と新しいことにも自分で対応できるようになっていきますが、最低限必要な時間と言うのはあります。今はまどろっこしいかもしれませんが、それなりの時間調べてそれでも残るような疑問は、他の方も疑問に思うことが多いはずなので、むしろ共有した方がサイト的に良いことだったりします。ちなみに時間が取れるなら、「自分でも解決できる問題はないか」なんて視点でQ&Aサイトを覗いてみるのも自分の理解度を深める役に立ちます。特にiOSプログラミングは、公式ドキュメントははっきり書いていないお約束が沢山あって、自分だけで原典をたどっていくなんてことは非常に困難です。ここのようなサイトもうまく利用していって下さい。

Comment: はい！ありがとうございます。続ける活力になりました。やはり近道はないんですね。まだまだやるべきことが多い様ですので日々精進していきたいです。